# ModuleNameMismatch mystery

Tags: rascal

Using rascal from the command line, when I type:

```
import demo::hello
```

I receive a `ModuleNameMismatch` error, although the current directory (the one in which I type `java -jar rascal-shell-stable.jar`) contains a subdirectory named `demo` containing a file `hello.rsc` :

```
module hello
import IO;
void hello(){
    println("Hello word");
}
```

It however works when I type

```
import hello
```

and the `hello.rsc` is in the current directory.

For your info: I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Alain, could you include the contents of hello.rsc in your question? I think the answer depends on this.

Comment: Thanks Jurgen. It works when I change `module hello` with its full path `module demo::hello` in the hello.rsc file.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with the operating system.

Comment: Ok great! Maybe you can add the answer here for future reference and accept it? Seems like something others might run into if they work outside an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module name must be the **full** relative path to the `module.rsc` file.

In this case, the `hello.rsc` file should be :

```
module demo::hello
import IO;
void hello(){
    println("Hello word");
}
```

That the reason why it does work when the `hello.rsc` in the current directory.